# How to create a Tencent Weibo (qq) share button?

Tags: html, social-networking, weibo

I need to implement the equivalent of the Tweet button for the Chinese translation of a website, that is, **not** the "share on Weibo" button, which I already got (using the generator [here](http://open.weibo.com/sharebutton)), but a Tencent/QQ Weibo share button.

What I've done so far:

- Subscribed to Weibo (reading the automatically Google-translated pages-I don't know Chinese)
- tried to go to the Q-Share page ([here](http://dev.t.qq.com/websites/qshare)) but the next page asks me personal info that I don't have (e.g. a Chinese telephone number, mandatory)
  [image: Q-Share next page button]

Are there alternative ways to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is the only way, but we made it work as follows.

First, it is **mandatory** to have a Chinese account, so ask someone in China (for example your client, or a colleague, which is what I did) to subscribe and fill in the required info. He/she will have to create and retrieve an app key (see below).

Then, add the following `script` tag anywhere in the page within the `<body>` tag (I've put it at the bottom for performance's sake):

```
< script src="http://mat1.gtimg.com/app/openjs/openjs.js#autoboot=no&debug=no"></script>
```

**Please note:** there's a whitespace between `<` and `script` because SO refuses to post the answer if it contains script tags: don't forget to **remove the whitespace** if you copy-paste the above code.

Lastly, add the following code where you want the QQ Weibo share button to appear:

```
<div id="qqwb_share__" data-appkey="YOUR_APP_KEY" data-icon="0" data-counter="1" data-counter_pos="right" 
data-content="title" data-richcontent="line1|line2|line3"
data-pic="pic"></div>
```

You'll have to replace:

- `title` with the title of the page
- `lineN` with a short summary of the page
- `pic` with the URL of an image

these will show up on the shared item.

- `YOUR_APP_KEY` with the numeric app key assigned by QQ Weibo.

Comment: Not sure why this is a community wiki specifically. A very useful answer.