# Tencent Weibo API Web App ID

Tags: ios, social-networking, weibo

I'm trying to implement Tencent Weibo sharing on an iOS app. According to the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountStoreClassRef/ACAccountStore.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ACAccountStore/accountWithIdentifier:) you need to fill the Tencent Weibo Access Key when requesting permissions  (`ACTencentWeiboAppIdKey`in the `options` dictionary).

Can somebody guide me through the [Tencent Weibo](http://t.qq.com) web to get an App ID for my app?

I would say that you would need to visit [here](http://dev.t.qq.com/) to get the key, but the page just shows an empty background for me. Maybe the dev page doesn't work outside China? Can anybody over there check it out?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17445250/269753) looks relevant, but I'm not 100% sure it is talking about the same App Key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step to get AppKey and AppSecret: [here](http://dev.t.qq.com/wireless/intro/)

The SDK about download website: [here](http://wiki.open.t.qq.com/index.php/SDK%E4%B8%8B%E8%BD%BD#iOS_SDK)  and  [Git URL](https://github.com/heloyue/TCWeiboSDK). You can follow the example and just to change the AppKey, AppSecret, and share content.

The API document website: [here](http://wiki.open.t.qq.com/index.php/API%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3)

[ShareSDK](http://sharesdk.cn/) is also a good choice for you which have mentioned by @Allan.Chan

Comment: Does http://dev.t.qq.com/wireless/intro/ work for you? For me it just shows an empty background. Maybe it only works in China?

Comment: Still don't know why http://dev.t.qq.com show empty for me, but a colleague was able to access it and generate the key, so I will mark this as accepted. Also, more info on the app generation process: http://qr.ae/nnszF

Comment: [http://dev.t.qq.com/wireless/intro](http://dev.t.qq.com/wireless/intro) work for me, maybe you can access it using goagent. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a useful step-by-step guide (in English) for registering for a API access:

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lingwang/weiboguide/

The process on Weibo's site is indeed in Chinese. The guide gives some guidance here.

One other suggestion would be to download the Chrome extension Zhongwen Chinese Popup Dictionary. If you don't know the meaning of a Chinese character this extension allows you to mouse over for a definition. Will help locate username, password field etc.

Comment: Moved the accepted answer to this one as it's much more clear.

Comment: Moved back the accepted answer to the original one. I'm asking about Tencent Weibo, not Sina Weibo.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use sharesdk to do this [click here](http://sharesdk.cn)